# How to hide a menu item in joomla to registered users

Tags: joomla

I'm using joomla 1.5.23, what i want is to hide menu items to registered/logged in users. I'm able to hide the menu item from the public, but want it the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer does completely the opposite, ive found a solution using metamod for joomla. Here you can hide to the registered and show to the public.

Answer (score 0):

In `joomla1.5`, you can change the access level for the menu.

Go through the following path to change the permission.

**Admin => Menu => Main Menu(Menu type) => Select any menu => Check Access level as Registered and then click the save button.**

The following menu will be work only for the *registered* users.